# Elderly, Eldest, Elder, Elders, Elderlies

Tags: meaning

There is so much information on the internet and different sources tell us different information. Are my guesses correct?

- All the five can be used only with living creatures, not objects/things?
- All the Elder-like words have a negative shade compared to Old-like words?
- Elder and Elderly are both nouns and adjectives?
- Elderly - means old person.
- Elder - means old but less old than elderly
- Eldest - means a very old person, the oldest.
- Elders - means old people
- Elderlies - means old people in general.

Comment: I guess you are right @FumbleFingers

Comment: I didn't mean to imply any criticism of you personally for asking on "the wrong site". Apart from anything else, not everyone who asks here even knows about ELL (when I posted my comment, I just assumed you might be in that number). But since I see now that you've recently started being active there yourself, I'd be rather interested to know if you had any specific reason for choosing ELU this time (as opposed to simply not giving it much thought, which fortunately isn't exactly a hanging offence! :)

Comment: I though it concerned usage of the language rather than learning.

Comment: Fair enough. There doesn't seem to be general agreement on where to draw the line between the two sites. But to my mind, something like *How did these different usages arise?* is much more likely to suit ELU, whereas *What's the difference between these related usages?* is probably better asked on ELL (assuming those differences are something that most native speakers know and agree on).

Comment: It's hard for me as for a non-native speaker to see this line you've mentioned.

Comment: Indeed! And that *specific* factor is one of the reasons why we should be careful to avoid being unjustifiably critical of people for making what (some but not all) other users might consider the "wrong" choice of site.

Comment: 'Eldest' does not necessarily mean 'very old', just the oldest of a group. You could say "My eldest son is ten."

Comment: Note that an "elder" is also a type of tree. So "among the elders" may mean a forest, not a retirement community.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for clear distinctions where they don't necessarily exist. I'll try to answer as best I can.

- All the five can be used only with living creatures, not objects/things?

- I would say so, yes.

- All the Elder-like words have a negative shade compared to Old-like words?

- Certainly not.

- Elder and Elderly are both nouns and adjectives?

- "Elder", yes. "Elderly", no, except for the generalised way that many adjectives can be used, in "the elderly". "An elderly" doesn't work for me. (See note at end)

- Elderly - means old person.

- Yes, but as an adjective not a noun. (See note at end)

- Elder - means old but less old than elderly

- No. They're simply not comparable.
  As an adjective 'elder' is fairly unusual except in "elder brother/sister" and "elder statesmen", and when used otherwise is generally selecting one out of two (eg. "the elder of the brothers").
  As a noun, "elder" no longer has much to do with "old", but means 'experienced', or 'learned', or 'wise person', or sometimes even 'leader'.

- Eldest - means a very old person, the oldest.
- Yes. Like 'elder (adj)' it has the connotation of being the oldest of a particular group.
- Elders - means old people
- Not really. It is the plural of "elder (n)" in the sense I gave above.
- Elderlies - means old people in general.
- I've never heard this. I don't acknowledge "elderly" as a count noun.

**Edit**: note on "Elderly/elderlies" as a noun.
I said above that *elderly* does not exist as a noun, except in the general sense *the elderly* like many other adjectives.

Another user has pointed out that "elderly" is in Merriam-Webster as a noun. This is true, but:

- The GlowBe corpus of English (which distinguishes the origin of its citations) has no instances at all of *elderly* as a singular noun. It has 37 instances of "elderlies", 17 of which are from Singapore and Hong Kong, and only 3 each from US and GB. It has
- The NOW corpus ("News on the Web") says it has 52 instances of *elderly* as a noun, but on inspection, every one of the 52 is either *the elderly* or an adjective. It has 585 instances of *elderlies*, mostly from Asia and Africa.
- The iWeb corpus has 38 instances if *elderly* as a noun, but only one which *might* be singular (and I don't think it is): " because the only elderly I saw on board today came here with their whole family". It has 82 of *elderlies*.

To summarise:

- *elderly* as a noun does appear in some dictionaries.
- *elderlies* is used a little, especially in Asian and African Englishes
- I have not found a single clear use of *elderly* as a singular noun in the largest English corpora.

Comment: Everything you say is true, but as regards the "negative shade" business, I can't see anything specifically pointing out that ***the elderly*** is invariably at least *somewhat* "negative" (though obviously not normally "pejorative"), because it alludes to the physical & mental decline associated with old age. By contrast, ***the elders*** is invariably "positive", because it focuses on ***the wisdom that comes with age and experience***.

Comment: I've only ever heard "elderlies" used facetiously, as a mocking term for the old ("elderly" is fine).

Comment: @StuartF- in the 1980s UK a woman pregnant with her first child after a certain age (35?) was often noted on medical records as an 'elderly primagravida'. Maybe still?

Answer (score 4):

These words are all used when designating people.

They are not negative at all, even polite.

- Nouns :

  - **[Elder](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/elder)** *(plural **Elders**)* : Old person
  - **[Elderly](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/elderly)** *(plural **Elderlies**)* : The group of people the elders are.
- Adjectives :

  - **Elder** : older *(comparative)*
  - **Eldest** : oldest *(superlative)*
  - **Elderly** : old *(polite)*

### Edit :

According to the usage note in the Free Dictionary's definition of [**elderly**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/elderly) :

> However, when used as an adjective in describing a particular person, elderly has a range of connotations that go beyond the denotation of chronological age.
>
> On the one hand it can suggest **dignity**, and its somewhat **formal tone** may express **respect** : *sat next to an elderly gentleman at the concert.*
>
> On the other hand it can imply **frailty** or **diminished capacity**, in which case it may sound **condescending** : *was stuck in traffic behind an elderly driver.*

Comment: Some forums and sources write that it's better to avoid these words.

Comment: @SovereignSun please check my edit

Comment: nice examples. I can see now

Comment: Excellent examples. Each sentence implies why noting a person's age might be relevant -- so the positive or whatever connotation comes from context.